# Predictive Models for Detecting Outlier

Tags: data-modeling, modeling, prediction, data-science

I have a IP log data as sample and new to data modellling.

Could anyone suggest any packages which does predictive modelling to detect Outlier in the data.?

Any R packages or anything that I can  use? Any inputs will help.

Comment: Can you tell us something about this data?  Have you considered using classical methods such as removing any point which is, say, 2 standard deviations or more away from the mean?

Comment: yes. soemthing generated from http://www.ntop.org/products/netflow/nprobe/

Comment: are there any  good reference material  or sample R packages that do netflow analysis and prediction for  outliers